# How to insert crm php code in wordpress?

Tags: php

I want to insert crm integrations php code in Wordpress but not understanding where to insert & how to get the data in crm

Comment: Hello and welcome to WPSE, please have a look at this link and improve your question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your code in functions.php inside `wp-content/themes/your_theme_directory/`

You can add wordpress [hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) into this file, upload your CRM SDK files into this directory, and your integration will live there.

Also, you could look for any existing (possibly commercial) wordpress plugins, that allows integration with your CRM.